# Why does my UI look different

Tags: interface

Ive been watching some tutorials on how to do fancy shaders and stuff and ive been finding them very hard to follow as their UI is very different to mine. This is what i want my UI to look like, however i cannot find anything on the internet that suggests there are different UI settings in blender. [image]

[image]

This second image is what my UI looks like at the moment
I am also using blender 2.79

Comment: Here you have the default "dark"  theme but this can be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are two completely different versions of Blender.

You are using 2.79, the current stable official version, the tutorial you are following is for the upcoming 2.8 version, a major refactor of the application, currently in release candidate phase.

You can download both from the [Build Bot](https://builder.blender.org/download/), but have in mind that 2.8 is not ready yet and is not advised for production. While backwards compatible, both versions are also considerably different, so it is unadvised to switch between the two with the same project.